# Why does the value of reference to const int(bound to an int) changes when the value of the int is explicitly changed?

Tags: c++

What I expected would happen was that since the types of reference and i do not match i must have been converted to a temporary and then assigned to r2 but when I changed i explicitly to 53 r2 was changed as well

```
int i = 42; 
const int &r2 = i; 

i = 53;
std::cout << r2<<"\n";

return 0;
```

The same does not happen when I use double

```
double i = 42.4; 
const int &r2 = i; 

i = 53.7;
std::cout << r2<<"\n";

return 0;
```

Here the value that was printed was as expected 42

Comment: I am not saying that the non-constant cannot be changed but why does the value of the reference change when it is bound to a temporary, is it because const is a qualifier (I am using visual studio if it helps)

Comment: What do you mean by "bound to a temporary" ?

Comment: The type conversion through a temporary

Comment: "...since the types of reference and i do not match...". The matching in this case ignores cv-qualifiers. In the first example the types *do* match. Since the types match (ignoring cv-qualifiers), the reference is required to be bound directly to `i`.

Comment: If you think one move ahead, you in fact expect const references to be entirely useless, i.e. your examples being equivalent to `const int r2 = i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules of the language explicitly state that if the type of the reference is reference-compatible with the type of the lvalue initializer then the reference is bound *directly* to the initializer. See 8.6.3/5

> **5** A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>   — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>   — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”,
>   [...]
>   then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue.

Reference-compatibility allows extra cv-qualifications in the reference type. So, despite your extra `const` in your reference type the language still requires it to be bound directly to `i`. In other words, in your first example the types actually *do* match.

In your second example the types are very different, not reference-compatible with each other. Direct binding of reference does not take place.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different cases on your hands. Here

```
int i = 42; 
const int &r2 = i;
```

You have an object. And a const reference of the same type. `r2` may be bound to `i` directly. You may not use `r2` to modify `i`, but `i` itself isn't const. You essentially created a const view of the object.

This is by design, and when you think about it, very useful. Say we want to print a `std::vector` of a million objects. Our function should be passed a reference, and it better not modify the vector. So passing by "const view" of the vector is exactly what we need.

In the other case, you have an object of one type, and a reference to a completely unrelated type. The reference cannot bind directly, so indeed we get a temporary `int` created for it to bind with. That temporary and the original object are separate. As you observed.

Answer (score 0):

In the double case you are binding an const int reference so in that case a temporary (the conversion) is required, in the first case you are saying that the value can't be changed through the reference but nothing prevents the original from being altered.

Think of cases like a const volatile int & i = ...; There you are explicitly telling the compiler that i might change for reason that the compiler can not deduce.

Comment: So what you are saying is the reference r2 in the first case is bound to a i and the type conversion does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

before assigning to the reference of different type, the type conversion happens and the value will be stored in different location, to which reference will point to. r2 will not point to i if its of different type.  in your case `cvttsd2si` will called and double value will be converted to signed double word integer.
Check the assembly code generated for both the version of code below.

For different type

```
 #double i = 42 ;
 movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0   #, tmp90
 movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp) # tmp90, i
 # *.cpp:6:     const int &r2 = i; 
 movsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm0 # i, tmp91
 cvttsd2si   %xmm0, %eax # tmp91, _2
 movl    %eax, -20(%rbp) # _2, D.39824
 leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax #, tmp92
 movq    %rax, -16(%rbp) # tmp92, r2
```

When the variable and reference are same type.

```
# *.cpp:5:     int i = 42;           
movl    $42, -12(%rbp)  #, i       
# *.cpp:6:     const int &r2 = i; 
leaq    -12(%rbp), %rax #, tmp89
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp89, r2
```